# Purposes of control other then follow insignals and eliminate disturbances.

Tags: soft-question, control-theory

As far as I understand we have two basic "purposes" of control i.e follow insignals and eliminate disturbances. Are there other things we might wanna do with a control that are essentially different?

Comment: The goal of optimal control is to reach a desired state by minimizing a given objective function (e.g. time, control effort and state accuracy). So you do not have to necesssarily follow a trajectory. See fot bang-bang control. Note, that disturbance rejection can be understood as trajectory tracking with a constant position and external disturbance.

Comment: The goal of intelligent control is to reach a desired state or follow a desired trajectory using minimal information on the dynamics of the system. That is, machine learning techniques are used to learn the dynamics and how to control the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot remember the source unfortunately, but once I read something of the form "Instead of describing the dynamics of a system, control is about prescribing the dynamics". I think that captures it all.